# Duplex outlets in series AND parallel after GFCI

Tags: electrical, gfci

I am planning to add some devices/receptacles to a 20amp circuit in my house.  The following image shows the original circuit and my proposed additions.  I'm specifically concerned about my plan for wiring outlets after the GFCI tester (see items 12 thru 17 in the image).  Three outlets will be wired in parallel from a junction box directly after the GFCI tester, with two additional outlets wired in series off of one of those paralleled outlets.  Are there any problems with this plan?  Any input or confirmation is much appreciated.  Thanks!
[image: Old vs New Circuit Diagram]

Comment: None of your outlets will be wired in series. That's not how house wiring is done. They may be in _a_ series on various circuit branches, but they're always connected in parallel. If this doesn't make sense you might seek expert local help.

Comment: What kind of outlets are these?  Or rather, how many on this circuit will be ***receptacle* outlets** (as opposed to hardwired outlets such as lights)?  If >12, we'll need to know which state you are in. Will any of these receptacle outlets serve a kitchen, bathroom or laundry room?

Comment: Just duplex outlets (not GFCI) after the blank GFCI tester.  These new outlets will all be along the soffit of my house.  Intent is to use them for Christmas lights.

Comment: Here is the "blank GFCI tester" I refer to.  The intent is that this provides GFCI protection to all of the new outlets I'll place along the soffit of my house, while being easily accessible.  [link](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-20-Amp-125-Volt-Combo-Self-Test-Blank-Face-GFCI-Outlet-White-R98-GFRBF-0KW/206001151)

Comment: Are the existing outlets in the kitchen? Because if so, that circuit has to be dedicated to the kitchen. If it wasn't before, that's OK, it gets grandfathered in. But you can't make the situation any worse.

Comment: Kitchen is not involved.  My diagram shows that the original four outlets were all in the dining room.  The outlets I'm adding to that circuit will be outside along the soffit.  The new outlets will be non-GFCI outlets, but they will all be wired from the load side of a blank face GFCI tester...which should provide GFCI protection to all of those new outlets.  My concern is with the fact that I'm using a j-box to wire nut together several outlets immediately downstream from the GFCI tester.  Is this a problem?  I've only ever seen daisy chained outlets after GFCI.

Comment: I believe the word you're looking for is "Deadfront". Please desist calling it a "blank GFCI tester" as *that actually describes something else*...

Comment: Yes.  I did an internet search and "Deadfront" returns the device i'm talking about.

Comment: Also you may want to revisit "series" vs "parallel", those have very specific meanings in electrical.  Best to stick to plain English and avoid the jargon unless you have strong command of it.

Comment: What's going on with the 12/2 aluminum on the 20A breaker, by the way?!

Comment: I am concerned if you are adding too many outlets to an existing circuit. 20A breaker equates to 16A of estimated load to comply with 80% rule. Outlets figure 1.5A estimated allowance each. What I am most unsure of is if the fan has lights, and how many, and if the security light has 2 300W lamp sockets? (that's 5 amps worth). And are there any other runs on that breaker that you didn't diagram?
You might be better served with fewer outlets in key locations, and using approved cords to connect temporary outdoor lighting.

Not quoting exact code, just alerting you to some possible issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Electrical cable/conduit routing must be *tree topology*

You can also wire things in a "vine" topology, like 12-15-16-17 - after all, a vine is a *type* of tree.

You can also wire in a star topology (like 12-9-15-14-13). That counts as tree topology also.  (but with many connections, box fill rules must be followed just like anywhere else).

You can freely mix them all.

Here's the acid test: In your graphics editor, take your cabling diagram (remove the non-cablng elements like gray walls).  Now, grab the paint can tool, and pour purple color anywhere on the diagram.  *Does it fill the whole diagram?*  Then you have tree topology. Yours appears to pass.

Comment: The other way of thinking "series" vs. "parallel" would be: *parallel* = normal wiring of all hots together, all neutral together and *series* = hot into receptacle, output (which should be neutral) as hot into next receptacle, etc. then all coming back on one neutral from the end. Which would (a) not work at all when any one receptacle is empty and (b) have major problems when everything is plugged in.

Comment: @manassehkatz your way sounds like the actual meaning of the words.

Comment: I see.  I was erroneously using "series" to describe wiring from load terminals of outlet 15 to line terminals of outlet 16, and again from 16 load to 17 line (I think this is also referred to as daisy chaining).  And I thought "parallel" was the correct term referring to the fact that the lines for outlets 13, 14, and 15 are all wire nutted together with the same positive wire in j-box 12 (and the same for their neutrals, too).  Thanks for explaining my misused terminology.